# Java Exceptions check in main()

Tags: java

I have java project contains around 10-15 java files and number of classes. I want to return exit code 1 from catch block inside the main() if any exception occurred any where through out these programs. However all of the classes has exception catch blocks so that exceptions will be handled there itself and catch block inside main() cannot "see" it.

Is there any way to check whether any exception occurred anywhere in the project inside main() of start point without change any code in other files but only at start point.

Thanks
Noushad

Comment: No, you can't. You will have to restructure your code.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to modify the other classes to throw an exception to the caller so that you can catch the exception in `main` and return the exit code you want.

Comment: Downvoter, you have downvoted 5 of my answers in 2 minutes span without leaving any justification. You are obviously trying to take some kind of revenge. Before I complain to the moderators, please provide a justification.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Throw exception from all methods of all classes and catch it in `Main` method's `catch` block. Log exception and then do exit.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   try
    {
    ClassA.methodX();
    ClassB.method();
    }
    catch(Exception e) //use specific exception class
    {
     e.printsttrace();
     System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

**Class A**

```
class classA
{
   public static void methodX() throws Exception
   {
    try{
    //perform some operation
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
       //throw exception from here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? Add some details to improve this answer.

Comment: Someone is just downvoting everything in this question without reading it. Either trolling, or they feel it's a bad question that should not be answered.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that `catch (Exception e)` is a bad practice, the `main` method should not have a try/catch in it at all.  Just declare the `main` method with `throws Exception`.  Java will exit with a non-zero status if an exception occurs in the main thread.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Write a common "logging" function and call it from any relevant catch block. If you need to exit the program, use `System.exit`.

```
public class Defines {
   public static LogException(Exception exception) {
      ... 

      if (ShouldExitFromException(exception))
         System.exit(1);
   }
}
```

elsewhere in your code:

```
try {
   // some code
} catch (Exception exception) {
   Defines.LogException(exception);
}
```

But it will depend what your other catch blocks are actually doing, and to be honest, this all sounds like a bad idea. Logging exceptions might be ok, so you know where and when they're happening, but exiting the program for even ones that have been handled properly is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions